# How to insert new cells into UICollectionview

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to recreate the feed on the facebook app and I'm having trouble inserting the newly downloaded cells. The cells are being inserted, but like this SO question: [Trying to insert new items into UICollectionView but getting the same cells over and over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961081/trying-to-insert-new-items-into-uicollectionview-but-getting-the-same-cells-over) , it keeps inserting the same results, the initial first 10 posts in this case.

What i've done is this:

```
jsonRequest.getPosts(hashKey!, request: populateFeedRequest) { (succeeded:Bool, msg:String, results:[AnyObject]) -> () in
    var resultsAreDone:Bool!
    if succeeded {
        if (results.isEmpty == false) {
            ++self.lastFeedPostId
            resultsAreDone = true
        } else {
            resultsAreDone = false
        }
    } else {
        println("you weren't able to download the posts")
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        if (resultsAreDone == true) {
            var updatedArray:Array = [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]()
            self.postsView.performBatchUpdates({
                let resultsSize = self.feedArray.count
                var size = 0
                if let newArray = results as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                    for n in newArray {
                        self.feedArray.append(n)
                    }
                    size = resultsSize + newArray.count
                }
                var arrayWithIndexPaths = NSMutableArray()
                var i = 0
                for (i = resultsSize; i < size; i++) {
                    arrayWithIndexPaths.addObject(NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0))
                }
                self.postsView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths(arrayWithIndexPaths as [AnyObject])
                },
                completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            println("it didn't work")
        }
    })
}
```

the lastFeedPostId is used to grab the next 10 results from the server.

Also a sidenote: i'm doing this in the "cellforItemAtIndexPath" function. I'm using the current Indexpath to determine if I should pull the next 10 posts from the server or not. Is this correct, or is there a better way to do this?

Thank you so much!!